# authotkey rebind return to ctrl when held down windows

Tags: windows, emacs

I would like to use the `return` key as `ctrl` when held down (or "chorded"), primarily to make emacs easier to use (I rebound left capslock to ctrl without much hassle using AutoHotKey, but making the change described above to right return has proved..... difficult).

Comment: Where do you want to do this? In general in MS Windows? In bash? In Emacs? You used those 3 tags. The question seems unclear.

Comment: Windows, for use with emacs.

Comment: Put it in the question, please. Comments risk being deleted at any time. Thx. And in that case, what's the connection with bash? Should that tag be removed, or is it germane to your question?

Comment: Removed the bash tag.  Must have accidentally added it - but yes clearly it did not belong.  Hopefully the question is more clear now.